# Redirect with notice after form submission

Tags: wordpress

I create a sub menu page and there is a form on it. The data is processed by `admin-post.php`.

I use `wp_safe_redirect` to redirect back to the previous page after the form is submitted. Now I'm trying the `admin_notices` hook to display a message to inform user by showing a message after the redirect. But the notice won't show, what am I doing wrong?

```
add_action( 'admin_post_hidden_value_of_form', 'setting_response' );

function setting_updated(){
   ?>
   <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
    <p>Saved successfully!</p>
   </div>
   <?php
}

function setting_response() {
   wp_safe_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=plugin-setting-url' ) );
   exit;
   add_action( 'admin_notices', 'setting_updated' );
}
```

Comment: When you use 'exit', you terminate the current script. So you are not adding the action, therefor the 'setting_updated' function is not being executed.

Comment: @rank I know, but I need the notice to be shown after the redirect. Any way to do this?

Comment: You can add a parameter to the url (in wp_save_redirect) and create a function on the target page that checks for a parameter in the url. if true, show message

Comment: @rank Thanks, if I create a function on the page, how do I init this function because it already exit after the `wp_safe_redirect`? If I just simply add the condition into a logicc like `if($pagenow==='urlHere')`, wouldn't this impact the performace because it run on every page even there is no action is done like my origianl intention is to show this only whena  form is submitted.

Comment: You should put the "URL-check" on the page you would like to display it (maybe using hooks, depends on the page you want to output). This way, you will only check the condition on every page, just the one you need it.